# Android Listview opens to another listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have currently implemented a listview, which when you click an item opens a second activity. In the second activity I have another listview which i can add items to, but when i go back to the first list and click another item, all the items from the second list appear for this one as well.

Any ideas how to sort this out? Can post code if needed

Here is the code for the first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> entries;
private ArrayAdapter<String> entriesAdapter;
private ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createListView();
    createListViewListener();
}

private void createListView() {
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.diaryListView);
    entries = new ArrayList<>();
    readEntries();
    entriesAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, entries);
    list.setAdapter(entriesAdapter);
}

private void createListViewListener() {
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            entries.remove(position);
            entriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            writeEntries();
            return true;
        }
    });
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("entry", entries.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void addEntry(View v) {
    EditText entryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entryEditText);
    String diaryText = entryEditText.getText().toString();
    entriesAdapter.add(diaryText);
    entryEditText.setText("");
    writeEntries();
}

private void readEntries() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File journalEntriesFile = new File(filesDir, "journalEntries.txt");
    try {
        entries = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(journalEntriesFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        entries = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to save a list of tasks
 */
private void writeEntries() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File journalEntriesFile = new File(filesDir, "journalEntries.txt");
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(journalEntriesFile, entries);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the second:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private String entryName;
private TextView entryTitle;
private ArrayList<String> entryTask;
private ArrayAdapter<String> entryTaskAdapter;
private ListView entryTaskList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    displayEntryTitle();
    createEntryTaskListView();
    createEntryTaskListViewListener();
}

private void displayEntryTitle() {
    entryTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryTitle);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    entryName = intent.getStringExtra("entry");
    entryTitle.setText("" + entryName);
}

private void createEntryTaskListView() {
    entryTaskList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.entryTaskListView);
    entryTask = new ArrayList<>();
    readEntryTasks();
    entryTaskAdapter = new CustomAdapter2(this, entryTask);
    entryTaskList.setAdapter(entryTaskAdapter);
}

private void createEntryTaskListViewListener() {
    entryTaskList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            entryTask.remove(position);
            entryTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            writeEntryTasks();
            return true;
        }
    });
    entryTaskList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            View view2 = (LayoutInflater.from(SecondActivity.this)).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Edit Journal Task Entry");
            alertBuilder.setView(view2);
            final EditText editEntryTaskText = (EditText) view2.findViewById(R.id.editEntryTask);

            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String editEntry = editEntryTaskText.getText().toString();
                    editEntryTaskText.setText("" + editEntry);
                }
            });
            Dialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

public void onAddEntryTask(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entryTaskEditText);
    String entryTaskText = editText.getText().toString();
    entryTaskAdapter.add(entryTaskText);
    editText.setText("");
    writeEntryTasks();
}

private void readEntryTasks() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File taskEntriesFile = new File(filesDir, "taskEntries.txt");
    try {
        entryTask = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(taskEntriesFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        entryTask = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

private void writeEntryTasks() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File taskEntriesFile = new File(filesDir, "taskEntries.txt");
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(taskEntriesFile, entryTask);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you populate the second `ListView`. Also the code where you call the activity containing it. Be as concise as possible. Thank you.

Comment: "when i go back to the first list"....and how do you do that?  I'm guessing arraylist type issue but show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: @SmulianJulian I've posted the code from both the activities, if you need anything else let me know thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you get back to the first activity from the second activity I can only assume that ArrayList entrytask is getting inserted into ArrayList  entries when you return so based on the limited information I have the best answer I can come up with is

```
private void createListView() {
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.diaryListView);

entries = new ArrayList<>();
list.setAdapter(null);
//ArrayList<String> entries = null;
readEntries();
entriesAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, entries);
list.setAdapter(entriesAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm fairly new to android, what do you mean by going back to the first activity? I just press the back button on the tablet, should i be implementing a method to go back? Also the entries.setAdapter(null); the setAdapter bit is coming up as cant be resolved.

Comment: The same way you go from the first to the second activity is the same way you go back to the first one. Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);